# Caused by PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000] - php unit test in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to laravel and php unit testing.
I am trying to run a very basic test in laravel and getting the error below while running `phpunit` through command line:

> Caused by PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'after `impressions`, `clicks` int not null, `clicks_change`
>   float(4, 2) not null' at line 1

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase {

    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testStats()
    {
        $result = true;
        $this->assertEquals(true, $result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the query that you are are trying to do assertion ?

Comment: There is not any, I need to test apis, but I am assuming `assertEquals` to be success first. I think I am missing something very basic.

Comment: Anything I am doing inside `testStats()` giving the same error. @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: The error states its a mysql error perhaps see if you are calling a class constuctor which is casing the issue.

Comment: I guess the error is caused by TestCase::setUp(). Maybe it is making an application and somewhere there a query is executing. Have you set app/database configs correctly?

Comment: could you drop the full stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the query you have written.
Or comment out DB related part from your phpunit.xml to run the tests without no db interaction

```
    <!--<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>-->
    <!--<env name="DB_DATABASE" value="event_test_db"/>-->
```